# Passing a string from variable as a key in javascript object literal

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

How can i do this?

```
objPrefix = btn.attr('data-objprefix'); //<button data-objPrefix="foo">
var sendData =  {objPrefix : {"bar":"ccccc"}};
```

ANd I want the output to be

```
{"foo" : {"bar":"ccccc"}};
```

but instead it is

```
{"objPrefix" : {"bar":"ccccc"}}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you use the literal notation `objPrefix` is considered as the keyname itself and not value of the variable `objPrefix`, Instead try use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects) to set the property name for the object based on a variable value. So try this way:

```
var sendData = {};
sendData[objPrefix] = {"bar":"ccccc"};
```

Also you can infact use jquery data-api to fetch the value of data-attribute i.e

```
objPrefix  = btn.data('objprefix')
```

Comment: @ideate if it worked, you should mark this as the answer by clicking the check-mark next to the vote count.